# mlr: Error in makeClassifTask: Assertion on 'data' failed: Columns must be named according to R's variable naming rules

Tags: r, dplyr, mlr

I have an error

```
library(mlr)
library(dplyr)
tree <- read.csv("file.csv",  header = T,  na.strings=c("", "NA")) 

tree$hipo = as.factor(tree$группы==1) # this variable has 3 levels i want to get 2
df = select(tree, - группы)
trainTask <- makeClassifTask( data = df,target = "hipo")
```

and i get

```
Error in makeClassifTask(data = df, target = "hipo") : 
  Assertion on 'data' failed: Columns must be named according to R's variable naming rules.
```

Then i do as below

```
tree <- read.csv("file.csv",  header = T,  na.strings=c("", "NA")) 
tree$группы = as.factor(tree$группы==1)
trainTask <- makeClassifTask( data = tree,target = "группы")
```

That's correct!
So the problem is in `select`? I try to reproduce this with a toy example

```
df = data.frame('пер'= c(1,0,2,0,1,2), 'b' = c(1,1,0,0,1,0), 'c' = c(1,1,0,0,1,0))
str(df)
df$d = as.factor(df$пер==1)
df1 = select(df, - пер)
trainTask <- makeClassifTask( data = df1,target = "d")
```

That's correct! what could be the problem? cyrillic names?
And i checked names with `make.names`

Comment: What's the output of `names(df)` and `make.names(names(df))`? are they identical?

Comment: yes
`names(df)
[1] "пол"  "Do"   "Sy"   "Sp"   "Lp"   "Ie"   "Fx"   "hipo"
> make.names(names(df))
[1] "пол"  "Do"   "Sy"   "Sp"   "Lp"   "Ie"   "Fx"   "hipo"`
The problem is lost when I change cyrillic to latin...

Comment: Can you post a complete example that allows to reproduce the problem please?

Comment: The cyrillic names are the problem in the task generation as you can easily see when you just try to run `makeClassifTask(data = df, target = "c")` on your last small example. We could allow this internally but I am always afraid that allowing non latin characters will break things in other places.

Comment: You can make syntactically valid names using the following approach: `colnames(df) <- make.names(colnames(df),unique = T)`